# MATLAB create a matrix M = F(i,j)

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

Suppose I have a function of 2 variables `F(i,j)` which depends on the row index and column index of a matrix, and I want to fill the matrix with the values `M_ij = F(i,j)`

Of course it's possible to do a loop through `i` and `j`, or even only `i` or `j` if the function `F` can be vectorized, but I'd like to know the neat way to do that.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What is your function? What are the inputs? What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Provide an example of F. If it takes vector inputs, you can pass in i and j that are the same size as M, where every row of i is the same and every column of j is the same.

Comment: The answer entirely depends on the function  `F`. You need to tell what it is

Comment: @excaza you don't understand the question, but other people have understood very well. F can be any function of 2 variables. that was very clear from the formalism. Thank you Mad Physicist.

Comment: @IKavanagh  you don't understand the question, but other people have understood very well. F can be any function of 2 variables. that was very clear from the formalism. Thank you Dan

Comment: lol, no they didn't. They gave a generic answer to a poorly posed question.

Comment: @NKN you don't understand the question, but other people have understood very well. F can be any function of 2 variables. that was very clear from the formalism. Thank you Mad Physicist

Comment: @LuisMendo  you don't understand the question, but other people have understood very well. F can be any function of 2 variables. that was very clear from the formalism. Thank you Dan

Comment: it was a generic question, i was expecting a generic answer

Comment: @Adriaan you don't understand the question, but other people have understood very well. F can be any function of 2 variables. that was very clear from the formalism. Thank you Mad Physicist

Comment: @FaguiCurtain I think I understood it pretty well. In fact, the answer you accepted says explicitly that the code is only valid _if the function is vectorized_. That's what I meant when I said that the answer depens on the function `F`

Comment: @Luis Mendo. there might have been other answers. Apart from the solutions given, is there another way to vectorize a function of two variables with numerical values ? i was thinking of using something like `arrayfun` and some function or syntax which retrieves the row and column number and that we can use in the definition of the matrix

Comment: @FaguiCurtain `arrayfun` is **not** vectorization. As mentioned numerous times here, the only way for anyone to help you vectorize your function is if you POST THE CODE

Comment: @FaguiCurtain As I said, there's not a generic solution. It completely and unavoidably depends on your specific function `F`. `arrayfun` is not vectorizing, it's a loop in disguise

Comment: Dan gave an example of a few functions that i had in mind. for example F=sin(i+j). or F=choose(i,j)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to answer without seeing your `F` but let's assume that `F` is vectorized such as

```
F = @(x,y)x+y;
```

then you could use `ndgrid`:

```
[I,J] = ndgrid(1:m,1:n);
M = F(I,J)
```

In the above case, and this may well apply in your case as well, you might be able to vectorize the function directly using something like `bsxfun`:

```
M = bsxfun(@plus, 0:m-1, 1:n);
```

Comment: Your indices are backwards in the call to F

Comment: I meant either `M = F(J, I)` or `[J. I] = meshgrid(...)`, otherwise `M` will be transposed.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's why I switched to use `ndgrid`. `meshgrid` is meant for images, it was a typo. When working with matrices you should use `ndgrid` which won't switch the dimensions.

Comment: @Dan This answer is as good as it gets, given the current formulation of the question

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether your function `F` is vectorized or not, you have to evaluate it for every value of `i` and `j`. If `F` is not vectorized, you will have to do a loop over the indices manually. If `F` is based on MATLAB builtins like `sin`, `log`, etc., it is most likely vectorized. In this case, you can pass in `i` and `j` that are the same size as `M` and get the result in one step:

```
[j, i] = meshgrid(1:size(M, 2), 1:size(M, 3))
M = F(i, j)
```

Note that [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) takes and returns the parameters as `X, Y`, which is the opposite of matrix indexing order `row, col`.